# Ansible declare host from variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

So i'm running an ansible playbook, which creates a server (using terraform) and gives saves the ip-address of the server into a variable. i'd like to execute another task on the given ip-address. How do i declare the new host?

I've tried:

`- hosts: "{{ remotehost }}"
  tasks:
  - name: test
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/environment
      line: test1234`

I run the playbook with: `ansible-playbook variable.yaml --extra-vars='playbook=ip-address'`

Comment: The solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519735/can-ansible-variables-be-used-to-declare-hosts-in-a-playbook doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to execute a single task you can use `delegate_to`

For example:

```
tasks:
  - name: another host execute
    command: ls -ltr
    delegate_to: "{{ remotehost }}"
```

The server should have the ssh connection working with the new hosts